# Problems with mongodb php functions

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm having several problems with an implementation in `php` for working with `mongoDB`

My case is that I made a function which recover an `mongoDB` database in `$_SESSION['mongoDb']` variable, selects a collection and then use the function `find($where, $fields)`.

My error is

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in...
```

I've tried checking mongodb php driver and others but the problem still existing...

EDIT: More info about.

Thanks for the post Eternal1, it's a bit confusing because same code is working in a production server but not my localhost XAMPP server.

For the one who ask me for the code, here you are:

```
public function generic_select_mongo ($collection, $fields, $where, $order, $limit)
    {
    $mongoBd = $_SESSION['mongoBd'];
    $col = $mongoBd->$collection;

    $res = $col->find($where, $fields);
    $res->sort($order);
    $result = array();

    while ($docs = $res->getNext())
        {
        $result[] = $docs;
        }

    return $result;
    }
```

I'm gonna investigate about Session in php. Sorry for the answer with additional info.

Answer (score 0):

`MongoDB` connection, as other DB connections, is of `resource` type, which can't be serialized and therefore properly stored into session. PHP session manual states:

> Some types of data can not be serialized thus stored in sessions. It
>   includes resource variables or objects with circular references (i.e.
>   objects which passes a reference to itself to another object)

[PHP Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

Comment: So, how can I save Mongo Object in a Session variable of similar for work with in another function?

Comment: I still working on it. How can I save new Mongo(conectionstring) such as Session for working in another part of my project?

Comment: I would recommend using some kind of `Dependency Injection` or `Service Locator` patterns.